# Foreach inside hash table with powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, hashtable

Is there a way to insert foreach loop inside hash table.

Something like this?

```
$vms = get-vm
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
   $disks=Get-Vhd  $vm.id
   $hash = [ordered]@{
        'VM<br>Name' =  $vm.vmname 
         'State' = $vm.state
         'Disk' = foreach ($disk in $disks) {$disks.size -join '.' }

    }
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = foreach ($disk in $disks) {$disks.size -join '.' }
$hash = [ordered]@{
     'VM<br>Name' = $vm.vmname 
     'State'      = $vm.state
     'Disk'       = $data
}
```

Comment: I tested a little and I think it will resolve my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Found it. Thank you :)